# Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format

Tags: android, build, unity-game-engine, apk

Please help me to solve this problem. This is what i got in the console:

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe -Xmx1024M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="D:/Android SDK/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "D:/Unity3D/Data/BuildTargetTools/AndroidPlayer\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:       Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/qn;
at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:732)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:130)
1 error; aborting
]
stdout[
processing archive bin\classes.jar...
processing com/unity3d/player/a$1.class...
processing
```

and a million of procesing somethings ... it took 320k line so i wasnt able to paste it here.

Comment: You will likely receive some more help if you post your code and describe your desired outcome.

Comment: i just want to build apk just it

Comment: we can't help unless you provide details.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxqarX4aBkGSZU5ER2F2Z2hheEU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: here is the full code. i made a 2d game hwo just contain ongui function i have added facebook sdk, google ads sdk, i have installed all the android sdk from sdk manager, i have installed admob plugin vntis. but i havent used facebook sdk. and my pc is 64 bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens for the plugins. Search for any duplicate jar in the explorer of your project. Delete any duplicates. If it doesn't solve your problem, try deleting your "Plugins" folder of your project and then re-import all your plugins. Hope it will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by simply changing the java path from Open Unity go to Edit --> Preferences --> External Tools in JDK . (this jdk folder was actually running on system).