# Unable to convert to DEX format

Tags: java, android, plugins, unity-game-engine, dex

I'm using Unity5, JDK 1.8 and I'm building for min android sdk = 10 and max = 22.

I can do a development build without any problems but when I'm trying to create an .apk file for the Google Play Store I get an error.

Error log:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.
F:/Java/JDK\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="F:/Android/SDK\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "F:/Programs/Unity5/Editor/Data/BuildTargetTools/AndroidPlayer\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:129)
1 error; aborting
]
```

And then a lot of lines that go like "processnig [path to .class file]".

I've tried switching to JDK 1.7 but to no avail.

I think I've eliminated the possibility of the multiple plugin error as there are no duplicate .jar's.

Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: How are you trying to create the apk?

Comment: By building the project in Unity

Comment: Have you seen this? http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unable-to-convert-classes-to-dex-format-android-issue.197061/

Comment: I've seen something simmilar, they're talking about the multiple plugin error and I've checked I have no duplicate .jar's.

Comment: I explained the general solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260722/error-building-player-commandinvokationfailure-unable-to-convert-classes-into/40644109#40644109

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

For some reason the classes.jar file in the Unity program folder was corrupted, I replaced it with the one I had in my Android Studio project and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead.

In my projects there were two androidAppCompact files were there 1.0.6 and 1.0.7. I deleted 1.0.6 and now its working fine