# Debugging a Unity Android "Unable to convert classes into dex format" error on build

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I've been having trouble doing an Unity Android build because of these dex format errors.

I've looked at similar errors people have had with this involving duplicate .jar files in the Unity project, but I've removed all the culprits I can find and this is still happening.  I recently updated the unity Facebook plugin and there are several other plugins in the project as well, so I know I would be prone to have some duplicate files.

I can see there a lot of "illegal argument exception" already added translations errors, so I'm assuming something is getting referenced twice, but I can't figure out where these "accessibility service" files are.

I'll admit the rest of the error I'm still trying to figure out.  I'm not a super experienced java/android developer just yet.

Does anyone know what might be wrong?  Or have any ideas of how I might go debugging this error further?

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="/Users/Admin/Public_Library/Android/sdk/tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/BuildTargetTools/AndroidPlayer/sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoJellyBeanMr2;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoStubImpl;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatJellyBeanMr2;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$1;

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:608)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:600)
    ... 9 more
]
```

Comment: I explained the general solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260722/error-building-player-commandinvokationfailure-unable-to-convert-classes-into/40644109#40644109

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong, it looks like I still had a duplicate .jar file in the project.  There were two .jar files with different names from two different social plugins but they were same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You need remove: Assets/Game/Plugins/Android/android-support-v4.jar