# CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

Get this Error When I try to Implement google play leaderboard, Please I will appreciate any insight into this problem as its hampering my progress in my work.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.
E:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="E:/NVPACK/android-sdk-windows\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "E:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/actions/ItemListIntents;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/actions/NoteIntents;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/actions/ReserveIntents;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/actions/SearchIntents;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$zza;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/AccountChangeEvent;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/AccountChangeEventsRequest;

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:608)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:600)
    ... 9 more
]
```

Comment: I explained the general solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260722/error-building-player-commandinvokationfailure-unable-to-convert-classes-into/40644109#40644109

Comment: Thanks A Lot it helped