# Unable to convert classes into dex format Admob 3.0.1 - Google Play Games 0.9.33 - Unity3d 5.3.2f1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

When I install Admob 3.0.1 , Google Play Games 0.9.33 seperately they work fine, but when I install them together I get this error:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
>   See the Console for details. C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M
>   -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/FX8/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1\tools"
>
> ### -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar"
>
> stderr[ Uncaught translation error:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zznm; Uncaught translation error:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zznn; Uncaught translation error:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzno; Uncaught translation error:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzno$zza; Uncaught translation error:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zznp; Uncaught translation error:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zznq; Uncaught translation error:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzqi; Uncaught translation error:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzqi$zza; Uncaught translation error:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzqj; 9 errors; aborting ] stdout[
>   ignored resource C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\Admob3_01 -
>   Copy\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleMobileAdsPlugin\libs.\PLUGIN_JAR_GOES_HERE
>   processing archive C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\Admob3_01
>   - Copy\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleMobileAdsPlugin\libs.\unity-plugin-library.jar...
>   ignored resource META-INF/ ignored resource META

I tried disabling .aar and .jar files one by one but I couldn' find the conflicting jar or aar file. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I found the solution at:
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1176

Comment: I explained the general solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260722/error-building-player-commandinvokationfailure-unable-to-convert-classes-into/40644109#40644109