# Unity Android - Unable to convert classes into dex format

Tags: java, android

Someone Please help me in this. I'm trying to make an android app with google play game services. When I'm building an app it occurs errors with convert classes into dex format. Here is the error below:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/asus/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzqc;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzqd;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzqd$1;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzqe;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzqf;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzqf$zza;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzqg;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzqh;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzqh$zza;

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:613)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:605)
    ... 9 more
]
stdout[
ignored resource E:\android\Game\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleMobileAdsPlugin\libs\.\PLUGIN_JAR_GOES_HERE
processing archive E:\android\Game\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleMobileAdsPlugin\libs\.\unity-plugin-library.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/google/
ignored resource com/google/unity/
processing com/google/unity/BuildConfig.class...
ignored resource com/google/unity/ads/
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$1$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$4.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$5.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$1$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$4.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$5.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/PluginUtils.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$1$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/UnityBannerAdListener.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/UnityInterstitialAdListener.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/UnityRewardBasedVideoAdListener.class...
processing archive E:\android\Game\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\MainLibProj\libs\.\play-games-plugin-support.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/google/
ignored resource com/google/games/
ignored resource com/google/games/bridge/
processing com/google/games/bridge/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/NativeBridgeActivity.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenFragment.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenFragment$1.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenFragment$2.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenFragment$3.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenFragment$TokenRequest.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenPendingResult.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenResult.class...
processing archive E:\android\Game\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\OVRPlugin\libs\.\OculusUtilities.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/oculus/
ignored resource com/oculus/oculusplugin/
processing com/oculus/oculusplugin/BuildConfig.class...
ignored resource com/oculus/utilities/
processing com/oculus/utilities/BatteryReceiver.class...
processing com/oculus/utilities/HeadsetReceiver.class...
processing com/oculus/utilities/VolumeReceiver.class...
processing archive E:\android\Game\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\OVRPlugin\libs\.\SystemUtils.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/oculus/
ignored resource com/oculus/systemutils/
processing com/oculus/systemutils/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/oculus/systemutils/SystemActivities.class...
processing com/oculus/systemutils/SystemActivities$1.class...
processing com/oculus/systemutils/SystemActivitiesReceiver.class...
ignored resource E:\android\Game\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\OVRPlugin\libs\.\armeabi-v7a\libOVRPlugin.so
ignored resource E:\android\Game\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\OVRPlugin\libs\.\armeabi-v7a\libvrapi.so
processing archive E:\android\Game\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\OVRPlugin\libs\.\classes.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/oculus/
ignored resource com/oculus/vrapi/
ignored resource com/oculus/vrapi/loader/
processing com/oculus/vrapi/loader/AppLoader.class...
processing com/oculus/vrapi/loader/BuildConfig.class...
processing archive E:\android\Game\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\OVRPlugin\libs\.\vrplatlib.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/facebook/
ignored resource com/facebook/androidcompat/
processing com/facebook/androidcompat/AndroidCompat.class...
ignored resource com/facebook/sign/
ignored resource com/facebook/sign/lib/
processing com/facebook/sign/lib/FBSignSigner.class...
processing com/facebook/sign/lib/FBSignVerify.class...
ignored resource com/oculus/
ignored resource com/oculus/aidl/
processing com/oculus/aidl/OVRServiceInterface.class...
processing com/oculus/aidl/OVRServiceInterface$Stub.class...
processing com/oculus/aidl/OVRServiceInterface$Stub$Proxy.class...
processing com/oculus/aidl/RemoteConstants.class...
processing com/oculus/aidl/RemoteConstants$EntitlementResult.class...
ignored resource com/oculus/appmanager/
ignored resource com/oculus/appmanager/signature/
processing com/oculus/appmanager/signature/VRPackageVerifier.class...
ignored resource com/oculus/appmanager/vrsign/
processing com/oculus/appmanager/vrsign/VRSignVerifier.class...
ignored resource com/oculus/provider/
processing com/oculus/provider/OculusContent.class...
processing com/oculus/provider/OculusContent$Profile.class...
ignored resource com/oculus/svclib/
processing com/oculus/svclib/OVR.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/OVR$1.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/OVR$EntitlementFailureDetail.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/OVR$ServiceState.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/OVREntitlementChecker.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/OVREntitlementChecker$Checker.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/OVREntitlementChecker$Checker$1.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/OVRPackageUtils.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/OVRProfile.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/OVRServiceManager.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/OVRServiceManager$1.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/OVRServiceManager$2.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/OVRServiceManager$3.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/OVRServiceManager$4.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/OVRServiceManager$4$1.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/OVRServiceManager$ConnectionStatus.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/OnCompleteListener.class...
ignored resource com/oculus/svclib/callback/
processing com/oculus/svclib/callback/OVRCallback.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/callback/OVREntitlementListCallback.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/callback/OVROfferListCallback.class...
ignored resource com/oculus/svclib/item/
processing com/oculus/svclib/item/OVREntitlement.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/item/OVROffer.class...
ignored resource com/oculus/svclib/task/
processing com/oculus/svclib/task/OVRAsyncTask.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/task/OVRAsyncTask$1.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/task/OVRAsyncTask$2.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/task/OVRBundleAsyncTask.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/task/OVREntitlementListTask.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/task/OVRLaunchIAPCheckoutFlowTask.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/task/OVRLaunchIAPCheckoutFlowTask$1.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/task/OVROfferListTask.class...
ignored resource com/oculus/svclib/util/
processing com/oculus/svclib/util/OVRErrorCodes.class...
processing com/oculus/svclib/util/Util.class...
processing archive E:\android\Game\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.1.1\libs\.\classes.jar...
ignored resource .readme
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource android/
ignored resource android/support/
ignored resource android/support/v7/
ignored resource android/support/v7/app/
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$DisplayOptions.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$LayoutParams.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$NavigationMode.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$OnMenuVisibilityListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$OnNavigationListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$Tab.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$TabListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$Delegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$DelegateProvider.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$DrawerArrowDrawableToggle.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$DrawerToggle.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$DummyDelegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$HoneycombDelegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$JellybeanMr2Delegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$ToolbarCompatDelegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb$SetIndicatorInfo.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$2.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$3.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$4.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$5.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$AlertParams.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$AlertParams$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$AlertParams$2.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$AlertParams$3.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$AlertParams$4.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$AlertParams$OnPrepareListViewListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$ButtonHandler.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$CheckedItemAdapter.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog$Builder.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatCallback.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplBase.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplBase$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplBase$ActionBarDrawableToggleImpl.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV11.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV14.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV14$AppCompatWindowCallbackV14.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV23.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV23$AppCompatWindowCallbackV23.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$2.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$3.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$4.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$5.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$5$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$6.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionMenuPresenterCallback.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ListMenuDecorView.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$PanelFeatureState.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$PanelFeatureState$SavedState.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$PanelFeatureState$SavedState$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$PanelMenuPresenterCallback.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialog.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialogFragment.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatViewInflater.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NavItemSelectedListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat$Builder.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat$IceCreamSandwichExtender.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat$JellybeanExtender.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat$LollipopExtender.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat$MediaStyle.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompatImpl21.class...
processing android/support/v7/<message truncated>
```

Comment: I explained the general solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260722/error-building-player-commandinvokationfailure-unable-to-convert-classes-into/40644109#40644109

Comment: closely related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/44468420/81306.